# specify a list of allowed .php files to be executed by apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

For security reasons, I want to create a list of php files that can be executed by Apache, other files besides this should show an error (ie. 403)

I'm looking forward to do something like this in my .htaccess:

```
path/to/file.php
path/to/another/script.php
```

and if accessing path/to/unlisted/file.php should return a 403

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule for blocking requests to all but allowed URIs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/file\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/another/script\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: I'm getting 403 for all files

Comment: any ideas on how to specify a location without the index.php? For example http://example.com/something

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the question in your comment.

Comment: for example instead of RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/file\.php$ [NC], I'm looking to specify the location without the ending file.php. This is for example when a main domain or a subfolder with an index.php is accessed. This isn't working RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/$

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/ [NC]`

Comment: this works, but also enables access to other files inside the directory, and I want to specify only some

Comment: this seems to be doing the job
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/$ [NC]